# Autowired Object with null value - Java Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm a newbie at spring. Can someone explain me why I'm getting this error ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.api.asdistribuidora.repository.ItemRepository.save(Object)" because "this.itemRepository" is null
```

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemModel, Long> {
}
```

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("item")
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping
    private ResponseEntity<Object> save(@Valid @RequestBody ItemDTO dto, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
        }

        ItemModel itemModel = new ItemModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, itemModel);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(itemRepository.save(itemModel));
    }
}
```

Shouldn't spring be responsible to create `itemRepository`?

I've tried changing the Dependency Injection to constructor instead of @Autowired, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: hi & welcome, why-ever '"this.itemRepository" is null' ..it is not obvious from the posted. except one thingy (which in best case fixes the issue/in worse case doesn't matter):  `@Repository` annotation is not needed on a `JpaRepository`.

Comment: is your repository in the correct package? [Structuring Your Code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code.using-the-default-package)

Comment: Maybe you dont have the right dependencies so spring boot can make the auto configuration for you. Also depending on your spring boot version, you may want  @EnableJpaRepositories added to some Configuration class. Share some more code and give us more info